# Create driver for unknown device

Tags: windows, controller, driver, gamepad, winusb

I'm trying to make a driver for my gamepad, it's a cyberbike from nintendo wii!
i know that i can use gamecube adapter but i want to use the cyberbike method instead gamecube method, this because i would like to use the analog pedaling and learn how to make a driver for windows!
i have found that the output port from my cyberbike is an 2.0 usb port type b, so i've take a 2.0 usb type b adapter.
i've tried WinUSB but this won't install and actually my usb appear like Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)!
can anyone suggest me a way to follow?

Comment: Maybe this article will help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/implement-driver-entry-for-a-usb-driver--umdf-

Comment: I'll try this tutorial!